# Read lines from a text file in QML Qt/Quick

Tags: application-development, c++, qml

I need open a text file and read it's contents line by line  and store each lines in a string list in qt quick 2.2.

Can every one help me?

Comment: why did you change from javascript to qml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QML provides a partially-functional version of XMLHttpRequest.  It's good enough to load text files from the local files system, but that's about it.  An example:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
request.open('GET', 'test.txt')
request.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
    if (request.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        lines = request.responseText.split('\n')  // Assuming you've defined
    }                                             // lines as a property
}
request.send()
```

Note that only a portion of the XMLHttpRequest1 interface is supported.  Notably, only asynchronous requests are allowed.  I've written some more details [here](http://rschroll.github.io/beru/2013/08/12/opening-a-file-in-qml.html).

Comment: How do I actually use this data in my qml file ?
lets say... I want to use that text from text.file as text in my Text component in qml ? How do I do that ? I always get [undefined], and when I do request.toString() I get [object Object]

Comment: As the example shows, the data is available in `request.responseText`, but only after request.readyState advances to `XMLHttpRequest.DONE`.  XHRs are always asynchronous in QML, so you have to handle this in a callback.